# How to ignore overselect in listbox

Tags: c#, listbox

Currently I have 6 listbox. Im trying to select all 5 other listbox items in the same row as the one manually selected.

However, Im getting an error :

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.StackOverflowException'
>   occurred in System.Windows.Forms.dll
>
> Cannot evaluate expression because the current thread is in a stack
>   overflow state.

Below is an example of code for one of the listbox, repeated for all other listbox.

private void listBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

```
      listBox1.SelectedIndexChanged=1;
        listBox3.SelectedIndex = -1;
        listBox2.SelectedIndex = -1;
        listBox4.SelectedIndex = -1;
        listBox5.SelectedIndex = -1;
        listBox6.SelectedIndex = -1;
        listBox2.ClearSelected();
       listBox3.ClearSelected();
       listBox4.ClearSelected();
       listBox5.ClearSelected();
       listBox6.ClearSelected();
       int  a = listBox1.SelectedIndex;
       int b = listBox2.SelectedIndex;
       int c = listBox3.SelectedIndex;
       int d = listBox4.SelectedIndex;
       int f = listBox5.SelectedIndex;
       int g = listBox6.SelectedIndex;


        if (a >-1)
        {
           // listBox1.SetSelected(a,true);
            listBox2.SetSelected(a, true);
            listBox3.SetSelected(a, true);
            listBox4.SetSelected(a, true);
            listBox5.SetSelected(a, true);
            listBox6.SetSelected(a, true);
        }
        else if (b > -1)
        {
            listBox1.SetSelected(b, true);
           // listBox2.SetSelected(b, true);
            listBox3.SetSelected(b, true);
            listBox4.SetSelected(b, true);
            listBox5.SetSelected(b, true);
            listBox6.SetSelected(b, true);
        }
        else if (c > -1)
        {
            listBox1.SetSelected(c, true);
            listBox2.SetSelected(c, true);
         //   listBox3.SetSelected(c, true);
            listBox4.SetSelected(c, true);
            listBox5.SetSelected(c, true);
            listBox6.SetSelected(c, true);
        }
        else if (d > -1)
        {
            listBox1.SetSelected(d, true);
            listBox2.SetSelected(d, true);
            listBox3.SetSelected(d, true);
          //  listBox4.SetSelected(d, true);
            listBox5.SetSelected(d, true);
            listBox6.SetSelected(d, true);
        }
        else if (f > -1)
        {
            listBox1.SetSelected(f, true);
            listBox2.SetSelected(f, true);
            listBox3.SetSelected(f, true);
            listBox4.SetSelected(f, true);
           // listBox5.SetSelected(f, true);
            listBox6.SetSelected(f, true);
        }
        else if (g > -1)
        {
            listBox1.SetSelected(g, true);
            listBox2.SetSelected(g, true);
            listBox3.SetSelected(g, true);
            listBox4.SetSelected(g, true);
            listBox5.SetSelected(g, true);
           // listBox6.SetSelected(g, true);
        }


    }


    private void listBox2_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        listBox1.SelectedIndex = -1;
        listBox3.SelectedIndex = -1;
        listBox4.SelectedIndex = -1;
        listBox5.SelectedIndex = -1;
        listBox6.SelectedIndex = -1;
        listBox1.ClearSelected();
        listBox3.ClearSelected();
        listBox4.ClearSelected();
        listBox5.ClearSelected();
        listBox6.ClearSelected();
        int a = listBox1.SelectedIndex;
        int b = listBox2.SelectedIndex;
        int c = listBox3.SelectedIndex;
        int d = listBox4.SelectedIndex;
        int f = listBox5.SelectedIndex;
        int g = listBox6.SelectedIndex;


        if (a > -1)
        {
            // listBox1.SetSelected(a,true);
            listBox2.SetSelected(a, true);
            listBox3.SetSelected(a, true);
            listBox4.SetSelected(a, true);
            listBox5.SetSelected(a, true);
            listBox6.SetSelected(a, true);
        }
        else if (b > -1)
        {
            listBox1.SetSelected(b, true);
            // listBox2.SetSelected(b, true);
            listBox3.SetSelected(b, true);
            listBox4.SetSelected(b, true);
            listBox5.SetSelected(b, true);
            listBox6.SetSelected(b, true);
        }
        else if (c > -1)
        {
            listBox1.SetSelected(c, true);
            listBox2.SetSelected(c, true);
            //   listBox3.SetSelected(c, true);
            listBox4.SetSelected(c, true);
            listBox5.SetSelected(c, true);
            listBox6.SetSelected(c, true);
        }
        else if (d > -1)
        {
            listBox1.SetSelected(d, true);
            listBox2.SetSelected(d, true);
            listBox3.SetSelected(d, true);
            //  listBox4.SetSelected(d, true);
            listBox5.SetSelected(d, true);
            listBox6.SetSelected(d, true);
        }
        else if (f > -1)
        {
            listBox1.SetSelected(f, true);
            listBox2.SetSelected(f, true);
            listBox3.SetSelected(f, true);
            listBox4.SetSelected(f, true);
            // listBox5.SetSelected(f, true);
            listBox6.SetSelected(f, true);
        }
        else if (g > -1)
        {
            listBox1.SetSelected(g, true);
            listBox2.SetSelected(g, true);
            listBox3.SetSelected(g, true);
            listBox4.SetSelected(g, true);
            listBox5.SetSelected(g, true);
            // listBox6.SetSelected(g, true);
        }
```

}

Comment: Never use an empty Try-Catch.  Is `a + 1 > 0` another way of saying `a > -1`?

Comment: do you have only listBox2 fires SelectedIndexChanged event which handled in listBox2_SelectedIndexChanged?

Comment: @LarsTech Your're right.  Thank you!

Comment: @skalinkin Sorry Im not strong in english, but if i get what you meant, the answer is yes. Please take a look at my full code via the answer section. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Your code is probably changing the index within the SelectedIndexChanged event somewhere in your code.

Try using a flag instead:

```
listBox1.SelectedIndexChanged += listBox_SelectedIndexChanged;
listBox2.SelectedIndexChanged += listBox_SelectedIndexChanged;
listBox3.SelectedIndexChanged += listBox_SelectedIndexChanged;

bool changingSelection = false;

void listBox_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e) {
  if (!changingSelection) {
    int index = ((ListBox)sender).SelectedIndex;
    if (index > -1) {
      changingSelection = true;
      listBox1.SetSelected(index, true);
      listBox2.SetSelected(index, true);
      listBox3.SetSelected(index, true);
      changingSelection = false;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi. Apologies, Im new to programming so Im still trying to figure out what is going on in your code. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @Adrian Feel free to ask me anything you don't understand about my example.

Comment: Sure.  listBox1.SelectedIndexChanged += listBox_SelectedIndexChanged;
listBox2.SelectedIndexChanged += listBox_SelectedIndexChanged;
listBox3.SelectedIndexChanged += listBox_SelectedIndexChanged; whats does this do ?

Comment: is flag the same as FlagsAttribute ? What does it mean/do?

Comment: The flag is just referring to a boolean variable: changingSelection.  When its true, it ignores the code inside the `if` block, because when you change the selection of a ListBox, it will always fire this code.  The `listBox1.SelectedindexChange += ` stuff is assigning the event to the method. This is a manual way of wiring up the events instead of using the designer.  I assign each of the ListBoxes to use the same method.  Usually you only assign the event once, preferably in the form's constructor.

Comment: I had tried your codes. Thank you! It was what Im trying to do. However , its is unsensitive at the start and lagging at the back. I cant see to figure out why from the codes. Any chance you can help ?   The below is a recording that i took    http://screencast-o-matic.com/watch/cDelc11FrR

Comment: I can't see your code, but clearly your event handlers aren't subscribed in the form's constructor.

Comment: @Adrian Where are the event handlers getting hooked up?  The first part of the code I posted?

Comment: in the individual listbox



private void listBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
      
  {
            listBox1.SelectedIndexChanged += listBox_SelectedIndexChanged;
    
    }



 private void listBox2_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
 
      {

            listBox2.SelectedIndexChanged += listBox_SelectedIndexChanged;
        }

Comment: @Adrian Yes, you are.  You are adding handlers on every selection index change, so now it runs multiple times the more it changes.  Not good.  Remove your old handlers, and move the wiring to the form's constructor or in that load event.